# When I click the address bar folder/directory buttons, is there a way to make them open in a new window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, address-bar

In Windows XP, installing the software '[Explorer Breadcrumbs](http://www.minimalist.com/software/ExplorerBreadcrumbs/)' allows me to have an address bar similar to Windows 7 (directories are displayed as buttons that you can click to go to).

With Explorer Breadcrumbs in Windows XP, I can open a directory in the address bar in a new window by ctrl-clicking or middle clicking the directory button.

Is there a way to have this same functionality in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to achieve this exact behaviour but here's a possible workaround using the keyboard:

- press Ctrl+N to open the current folder in a new window
- press Alt+Up (arrow) to go "up" one level